# How to overcome getClientOriginalName() error in Laravel dropzone file upload?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using Laravel 5.0, for image uploading I am using dropzone.js. Actually file uploading to folder and database but it is throwing error like

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
>   on post method.

Where have I gone wrong?

View File,

```
<form  method="POST" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="productDropzone" action="{{url()}}/cms/website/pages/upload_files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                              <div class="dz-default dz-message">
                                <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
                              </div>
                              <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit_all"/>
                          </form>
```

Below is my js,

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#productDropzone", { 
    paramName : 'file',
    maxFilesize: 3, // MB
    maxFiles: 3,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) { fileupload_flag = 1; });
        this.on("complete", function(file) { fileupload_flag = 0; });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) 
   {
        var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        var ext = re.exec(file.name)[1];
        ext = ext.toUpperCase();
        if ( ext == "JPG" || ext == "JPEG" || ext == "PNG" ||  ext == "GIF" ||  ext == "BMP") 
        {
            done();
        }else { 
            done("Please select only supported picture files."); 
        }
    },
    success: function( file, response ) {
      obj = JSON.parse(response);
      file.previewElement.querySelector("file").src = obj.src;
      // alert(obj.src);return false;
    }
});
$('#submit_all').click(function(){   
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Controller function,

```
   $com_id     = Auth::user()->company_id; 

   $file = Request::file('file');
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/images/section/';
        $filename = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalName());

        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        if ($upload_success) {

            $upload = new Cms_banner_master();
            $upload->product_banner = json_encode($filename);
            $upload->company_id = $com_id;
            $upload->home_banner ="1";
            $upload->save();

            return Response::json(array($fileName));
            } else 
            {
            return Response::json('error', 400);

        }
```

Comment: You title and code show `getClientOriginalName`, however, you're error shows `getClientOriginalExtension`? Also, would you mind running `composer show | grep -i "symfony/http-foundation"` from your command line and telling us what version of http-foundation you're using.

Comment: since you are using multiple file upload, you have to access files as an array.

Comment: **composer show | grep -i "symfony/http-foundation"**

`Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.`
                                                     My composer version is,

`Composer version 1.0-dev (72cd6afdfce16f36a9fd786bc1b2f32b851e764f) 2015-12-28 17:35:19`

Comment: @JagadeshaNH,  `public function uploadFiles() 
    {
      $file = [];
         $com_id     = Auth::user()->company_id; 
            $file[] = Input::file('file'); }`     I have changed it but not working.

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple ?

Comment: Your version of Composer is about a year out of date. It is worth upgrading it, as it says. It gives very clear instructions on how to do so, so please do that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent the error from happening, you can add some validity checks on the file first.

For example with the *isValid* method

**Update:** I added the *hasFile* method too.

```
if(Request::hasFile('file') {
    $file = Request::file('file');

    if($file->isValid()) {
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/images/section/';
        $filename = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalName());

        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        if ($upload_success) {
            ...
        }
    }
} else {
    return Response::json('No file uploaded', 409);
}
```

And I would also generate a new name for the uploaded file, this way you don't need the getClientOriginalName:

```
$filename = $com_id.'_'.date('YmdHis')'.'.$file->guessExtension();
```

In the spirit of "never trust the users" and not letting them 'choose' a file name from a file that you will be saving on your server.

Comment: If the file is present then only you can check for $file->isValid(), but looking at the error, the file itself is not present in the request.

Comment: @Hans Vn, Same erorr is coming still. I think is there any mistake in js file success function?

Comment: @Mohan, can you post a dump & die from the request ( dd(Request::all()); ), or maybe you can check for the file presence in the dump. -- I also updated the code example so it should be easier to debug your problem.